Даунгрейд kibana 8 версии до 7
Нахожусь в довольно ограниченной среде. Имеется ELK стек с Elasticsearch и kibana 7 версии. Нужно было обновить Kibana на чуть более выше версию, но по чистой случайности обновил на 8, из-за чего она не запускается из-за несовместимости версий с ES.
Можно ли сделать даунгрейд kibana, либо удалить и установить заново? В гугле долго искал, но так и не нашёл подходящего решения. Обновлять ES на 8 версию никак не вариант.
